# How To find Jaccard Similarity of classes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to find the Jaccard Similarity between each pair of groups in my data set. My data is as follows the first column is my data and the second column is class lable:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data' : ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7"], 'ClassLable' :     ["c1","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c1"]}); df
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data' : ["a1","a2","a4","a6","a7","a8","a9"], 'ClassLable' : ["c11","c21","c21","c12","c13","c13","c11"]}); df2
```

I want to calculate the Jaccard Index for each pair of Class Lables between df and df2. for Example:

```
c1class = pd.DataFrame({'Data':["a1","a7"]})
c11class = pd.DataFrame({'Data':["a1","a9"]})
Jaccard = 1/3
```

in other words, for df1 and df2 i want to find intersected items over union for each class lable

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for something like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score

jaccard_similarity_score(df['Data'],df2['Data'])
Out[92]: 0.2857142857142857

jaccard_similarity_score(c1class, c11class)
Out[93]: 0.5
```

Comment: No. i want to find the jaccard similarity between different groups of data. i want to compute the jaccard for each pair of class in order to find the similar classes based on the similar objects